# Hiding Default Controller Name in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

When my website opens for the first time , it directly goes to this address: http://www.website.com/tr/main

But I want my link to be like this: http://www.website.com/
I can't remove "tr/main" links. How can I solve this problem?

**Php Code:**

```
$route['default_controller'] = "main";
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['(tr|en)/(.+)$'] = '$2';
$route['(tr|en)$'] = $route['default_controller'];
```

**Htaccess Code:**

```
RewriteEngine On

# Put your installation directory here:
# If your URL is www.example.com/, use /
# If your URL is www.example.com/site_folder/, use /site_folder/

RewriteBase /

# Do not enable rewriting for files or directories that exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# For reuests that are not actual files or directories,
# Rewrite to index.php/URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [PT,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your config.php file write this code :-

```
$config['base_url']='http://Your Path/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'Base';
```

In your routes.php file write this code :-

```
$route['default_controller'] = "home";
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

Comment: are you running your project on localhost ?

Comment: Now "tr/main" link doesn't appear. Home page link is solved but this time the other links don't work. When the other links are clicked "tr" link doesn't appear so the other links except the home page don't work. By the way I'm not on localhost.

Comment: can you write your code for that other links.You have to write something like this suppose you are link for tr(button) will be <a href="<?php echo base_url;?>/tr/your_function_name"

Comment: <a href="<?php echo site_url('sayfa/' . $value->seo_url . '/' . $value->page_id); ?>"><?php echo $value->title; ?></a>

Comment: @YunusEmre: If this answer was helpful, upvote it. If it solved your question, please [mark it as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0):

Write the follwing code in your routes.php file :-

```
$route['default_controller'] = "main";
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

and then in your "main" controller i.e in main.php use

```
function index() 
{
    // write all your code inside this function    
}
```

Comment: if you got it please let me know

Comment: I'm already using the same code you wrote. Do I have to change anything in config.php file?

Comment: can you delete this code $route['(tr|en)/(.+)$'] = '$2';
$route['(tr|en)$'] = $route['default_controller'];   and then try

Comment: can you tell me what you had written in your config.php file in $config['base_url']= ?

Comment: It is blank. Nothing is written in it.

Comment: you have to write something as your default controller path.try this:-$config['base_url']=http://www.website.com/  i.e your project path

Comment: can you tell me what you had written?

Comment: $config['base_url']= 'http://www.website.com/'; I tried with hhtp or without http. But the problem goes on.

Comment: ok wait im adding another answer for you please write all those code into your project

Comment: please check the above answer